# JOIN on variable number of columns

Tags: mysql, join, php, database-design

I have the two tables `courses` AND `something_about_courses`:

`courses`

- `course_code`
- `course_session`
- `course_type`

`something_about_courses`

- `course_code`
- `course_session`
- `some_description`

To ensure that I fetch `some_description` only for `courses` that actually exist, I use:

`SELECT some_description
  FROM something_about_courses A
  JOIN courses B
    ON (A.course_code = B.course_code
   AND A.course_session = B.course_session)`

Okay, everything is good and the system is put in to use. Now, two year after the system is in use, the client wants to compare not just with {`course_code`, `course_session`} **but also with `course_type`**.

So I change the structure of `something_about_courses` to:

- `course_code`
- `course_session`
- `course_type`
- `some_description`

and I change to query to:

`SELECT some_description
  FROM something_about_courses A
  JOIN courses B
    ON (A.course_code = B.course_code
   AND A.course_session = B.course_session
   AND A.course_type = B.course_type)  <<<<<<< AND clause added to JOIN`

The problem I now face is that all old data in `something_about_courses` doesn't `JOIN` successfully since they have a `NULL` for `course_type` as it was a newly added column.

**In other words, I have working queries but a disconnect in the data sets.**

---

Solutions I have thought of:

- Date based segmentation: use the old query for before the feature change and the new query for after. However, this isn't elegant and has a huge amount of maintenance overhead.
- Manual adjustment of the old data: there is way too much of this to adjust it to be compatible with the new query to make this feasible.

Neither of the above solutions are ideal. I was wondering if there is anything I can do at the query level to `JOIN` on 2 or 3 columns based on whether `something_about_courses.course_type` IS `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Try and see if this yields the result you want:

```
SELECT some_description
FROM something_about_courses A
JOIN courses B
ON (A.course_code = B.course_code
AND A.course_session = B.course_session
AND (A.course_type = B.course_type OR B.course_type IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick solution, use the `<=>` operator, so

```
AND (A.course_type <=> B.course_type).
```

As a real solution, add a column `id` to course and let `something_about_courses` show to that id column.

EDIT: 
If you want to get rid of the NULL, you don't need to do that manually. What about

```
UPDATE A set course_type=-1 where course_type IS NULL;
UPDATE B set course_type=-1 where course_type IS NULL;
```

as long as no real course type is "-1"?

But definitely: Use An Index Column.